# Column in Data Table not appearing as Column in GT Table

Tags: r, gt

I'm hoping to get some troubleshooting steps on how to figure out the issue myself.  I have some sports data that I'm moving to a GT Table.  One column isn't being treated like a column in GT, and instead it's acting like a "summary" header for the data underneath.  I'm trying to figure out what things could cause it to happen this way.  Here is the code I'm running to make the table.

```
pac12_epa <- Pac_12_2010 |> 
  arrange(-off_ppa) |> 
  dplyr::select(team, logo, off_ppa) |> 
  gt() |> 
  cols_align(align = "center") |> 
  gtExtras::gt_img_rows(logo) |> 
  cols_label(team = "School",
             logo = "",
             off_ppa = "PPA Per Play") |>
  gtExtras::gt_theme_538() |> 
  gtExtras::gt_hulk_col_numeric(off_ppa)
#save the gt table
gtsave(pac12_epa, "pac12ppa.png")
```

And here is a snippet of what my output looks like:
[image]

The data in the column shows as a character type Character.  I've tried to match it to the sample data I'm using and I just don't understand what could be different, I'm hoping to get some tips on how to troubleshoot something like this so I can figure out what is happening.

Comment: Most likely reason is that you data is grouped by `team`. Try `ungroup` before passing to gt.

Comment: @stefan - That was it, thank you.  I'll add checking grouping to my list of troubleshooting steps.